# Save HTTPS response together with SSL signature

Tags: encryption, ssl, https, openssl

I'm building an app that should download file from a given url and store it locally, like a cache.

Now, I would like to be able to prove that the content was indeed downloaded from this url, and not replaced or tampered with. Most importantly, I should be able to do that if the original url is not available anymore or the server is down

Only solution I could think of is to somehow record all SSL communication with the server, and use SSL signatures to verify against the server's certificate

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The SSL logs will not give you a checksum of the file you downloaded. You might be able to prove that you downloaded some file from the server but that's about it. Also, how to you intend to verify against a server's certificate after the fact if the server is down or gone?

Comment: @doneal24 I thought about downloading the certificate chain and using it for the proof

Comment: The sure way is, if a hash exists for the source file, to check the hash of the downloaded file.

Comment: That would be best of course, but I don't have a reliable way to prove that this hash is indeed from the original source

Comment: @lobanovadik: The server does not sign the content. See also [Where in a TLS connection can I get the signature of the content sent by the server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/95213/where-in-a-tls-connection-can-i-get-the-signature-of-the-content-sent-by-the-ser). [Proving authenticity of data accessed over TLS by an untrusted third party](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/223186/proving-authenticity-of-data-accessed-over-tls-by-an-untrusted-third-party)

Comment: @doneal24: *"You might be able to prove that you downloaded some file from the server but that's about it."* - not even this.

Comment: If you don't have a hash, you can only be sure that you have contacted the right server, that's about it (assuming you have the right public key).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The download proof would be the webserver logs IF they were validated in some fashion. SSL transactions would not be sufficient. Hence, the _might_.